# Keeping margins when shrinking screen size?

Tags: html, css

I was testing my local website sizing when I realized that the margin space on the left and right (mostly the right) kept disappearing the more I shrunk the window.

I have tried editing the html and body CSS by specifying the margins such as 2rem or 50px but that didn't work and even tried the @media function but that didn't work either. The only thing those did was shirt the body which I didn't want it to do since it is supposed to be centered. This is what I have so far:

```
html {
  background-color: rgb(16,17,140);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cambria;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 65rem;
  background-color: rgb(35,145,241);
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

Is there a way to fix the margins during window shrinkage that doesn't impact the placement of the centered body?

Comment: is it margin or padding ? you have margin auto left/right and what you said is what auto meant to do, am i missing something here ?

Comment: It's margins. I want the body to be centered but when I shrink the window the margins disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the margins to `0 auto` - that will essentially center your element in the page. The problem is that you've set the width explicitly here to `65rem` (which is a bit of a weird practice - here's a deep dive on [REMs](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/))

Essentially, when you're on a large screen size right now, your width is capped at `65rem` so your `body` element will only be that big. `margin: 0 auto;` will otherwise center it. As it gets smaller, your body will stay that width - the margins appear to disappear.

Removing the width on the body and setting your margins explicitly should give you the effect you want.

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(35,145,241);
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3rem;
  margin: 0 50px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean using rem is "a weird practice"? Isn't using rems better than px because they're more flexible? I know the translation from px to rem can be a little difficult but other than that I thought they were better?

Comment: In answer to your question about "a weird practice" @President _ In a world of different sized viewing devices setting the body width to a specific number (in px or rem) forces restrictions (caps the size as stated by @LMulvey) _ Coding the width in such a way does seem a bit strange / 'weird' _ A more 'normal' way is to set width using percentage